# What causes an item to disappear in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What persists after a respawn in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7744/what-persists-after-a-respawn-in-minecraft)

I've apparently lost my diamond sword due to a death far from my spawn point. Was I just unlucky or do items disappear if you are so far/if they are on the ground for X minutes?

Comment: I also wonder if items persist if you quit and start again, and if they persist if you enter the Nether and return.

Comment: @Jonathan Drain: I think they persist. I quit and reloaded once, because none of my items were at the death point, but they reappeared after that.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate, can the two be linked together a little more obviously?

Comment: If we do merge them make sure to include the items disappearing text in the title. The previous question did not show up on the helpful title drop down and did not show up when I searched for 'item disappearing'
This may also be relevant: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Items will disappear if they are on the ground for 5 minutes after you die. This timer starts ticking as soon as you die; even on the death screen that timer is going to keep counting, so if you go take a break to grab some food and come back to find out your character's been lying around dead for 10 minutes, your items are gone.

Also, dying in lava or fire will make you lose any items that fall into the flames. Items that fall onto cactus are also destroyed.

Caveat: if you spawn far enough away from where you died and the chunk becomes unloaded, the item timers will freeze until the chunk is loaded again.

Comment: One interesting note: If you die so far away that the chunk is unloaded once you respawn, the countdown timer remains frozen until you visit that chunk again.  So you could theoretically come back to a place for the first time weeks after dying and you items would still be there, so long as your time while that specific chunk was in memory is less than 5 minutes total.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: If you die in lava it's likely that some if not all of your items will fall in the lava and be destroyed instantly. The same goes for fire.

Comment: @SeanO'Hollaren: is this true for SMP too?

Comment: @Lohoris: I believe it is. I just died WAY away from my bed and I had to even spend the night in someone elses building on my way there, not to mention that the day I died there was a thunderstorm so I couldn't start walking until the next day. When I got to the scene of the creepercrime, all the items were there. Some of the XP was gone though.

Comment: Yes, happened to me too not long after posting this comment.

Comment: @TorValamo Not all of the XP is dropped, only a percentage. Even this percentage is capped at five levels.

Comment: @Lohoris The SMP mechanics are exactly the same, except other people could visit the chunks and make your items despawn while you're away, which, for obvious reasons, wouldn't happen in single player.

Comment: I assume this applies for a death in the nether too? I just stumbled on some of my gear I lost many in game weeks ago (and came here looking for answers)

Answer (score 8):

As per **[this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7744/what-persists-after-a-respawn-in-minecraft-alpha)**, your inventory will stay around the point where you died for approximately 5 minutes.

If you die with creepers around, be aware that an exploding creeper (after your items have dropped) will probably destroy some/all of them.

From personal experience, sometimes the items kind of spray out around where you died, so do a few laps when you get there to make sure you got everything.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the purpose of being complete: items that fall into or are thrown into lava are destroyed immediately. (You can use this to your advantage if you're sick of storing stacks of dirt or something.)

Comment: Do sand blocks still turn into glass blocks before being destroyed? Or was that only in previous, non-alpha versions?

Comment: No, I believe you have to burn the sand in a furnace for it to turn to glass, throwing sand in lava simply burns up and destroys the sand.

Comment: In early, non-alpha versions, lava didn't destroy items, and you could toss sand blocks into lava to generate glass.  You could also use flint and steel to 'cook' blocks that were on the ground.

Comment: It's not exactly immediately. Items bounce up once when hitting the lava, which gives you a split second to pick them up.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if the game crashes while you're on your "body-run" there is a high likelihood that your stuff is gone even well inside the five-minute window.

Answer (score 2):

Some more info: Items get scattered in an area around you on death, and there is a glitch where they go through walls.
Another glitch makes your corpse pick up the items after they were scattered, and they get destroyed.
I believe these glitches account for the "there's a chance that items get destroyed on death" you read on the forums over and over again.

Comment: This also applies to Minecraft Pocket Edition.