# How long do dropped items of mobs (loot) stay?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long/What causes item to disappear in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11010/how-long-what-causes-item-to-disappear-in-minecraft)

Hey there,

i read here a lot about your own dropped item's, and that they will stay for about 5min after their drop ...

I was wondering, how often do i have to check my mob traps, to get the maximum amount of dropped items. So, is it the same situation with loot dropped by mobs, and therefore do i need to check the traps within 5mins?

Comment: I think this is covered well enough by other questions/answers.

Comment: all other questions/answers cover items dropped by players; until javier badia's answer, it was never stated that all dropped items behave the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same. All dropped items disappear after 5 minutes. The best way to gather the loot from mob traps is simply to stand in the collection point for a while. You can open your inventory so the game doesn't pause if you leave it and go do something else.