# Preventing item loss after death

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm really sick of getting all of my items destroyed when I die.

Is there any way, even by cheating, to re-acquire the items or to disable the [5 minute item-disappearance countdown](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11010/how-long-what-causes-item-to-disappear-in-minecraft)?

Comment: I can totally relate to that.  When I stumble across enormous caverns, I can't seem to pick the right moment to stop mining and go to the surface.  When I do, it's usually when I realize that I'm lost.

Comment: @Niel Worst case, just build a spiral staircase going straight up, then use your compass to get home.

Comment: @Neil Build safehouses with a chest to put goodies in so if you die, you lose less. (Also a good place to put furnaces and crafting benches.) As a bonus, the safehouses become landmarks that make it easier to get un-lost.

Comment: @Keaanu: The problem with spiral staircases is that they rarely spiral through the heart of the caverns, meaning you'd need multiple staircases or you'd have to spiral your way back up to the surface.  Only way I can find my way back is if I make a point to put torches on the right-hand side always so I know what direction led me there in the first place.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: You mean build safehouses in the caverns?  Not a bad idea.  I'll consider it.

Comment: @Keaanu, besides, a spiral staircase won’t work at all, at least not a 2×2; you’d have to build it wider.

Comment: @Synetech Not with proper stair blocks, no. But it's possible to carve out a 2×2 "staircase" using full blocks as steps. Yes, you'll have to jump onto each stair, but it's much quicker and more economical than a full 3×3 staircase.

Answer (score 22):

Risugami's has made a mod that will take items in your inventory and put them in a chest upon death.

> When you die, if you have a chest in your inventory, it will be placed where you die, or in the closest available spot. The chest will be filled with as many items as possible. Items stored in the crafting slot are still lost, as usual, and any excess that won't fit in the chest will be dropped.

[Here is the link on the Minecraft forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-v172-risugamis-mods-updates/) and here is a [direct download](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20629262/Latest/Death%20Chest.zip).

Answer (score 16):

If you have cheats enabled, you can use `/gamerule keepInventory true` to avoid losing items on death. This will cause the items to stay in your inventory on death.

Answer (score 12):

What you want is the [Death Chest Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-v172-risugamis-mods-updates/), which places a chest of your items at the spot you die.

Comment: Thank you very much it will do it. One last question: I quit the game in the respawn screen. I think it will automaticly respawn when I open the game so if I install this mod can I prevent what I already dropped? I had a chest with me.

Comment: No, I'm afraid you won't be able to recover items from a previous death :-( Since you don't mind a little cheat here and there, consider using [InvEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/14190-invedit/) to restore your lost inventory on this occasion.

Comment: Thank you. It will be really great if I can use that invedit thing :)

Comment: InvEdit it great, [TooManyItems](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/140684-172-toomanyitems-in-game-invedit-july-1/) is *amazing*. I use it for my creative projects. It's a little more effort to install, but well worth it if you don't mind that it's not 'legit'.

Answer (score 7):

Install the [Death Chest mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-risugamis-mods).

Or, if you die miles away from spawn, I suggest you use the [TooManyItems mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/140684-toomanyitems-in-game-invedit) and save your inventory, so you can reload it when you die.

Answer (score 5):

Take lots of signs, and signpost the way out. Wear armour, and take cooked porkchops. Build safehouses with chests as you go, and discipline yourself to offload your stuff when you know you're entering a possibly dangerous area.

Comment: Mmmmm.... Pork chops.

Answer (score -3):

There are a few different ways of doing this:

1. Download the [Death Chest Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-v151-risugamis-mods-updated/) and the chest will place itself and throw as many items as possible into it.
2. Have the */gamerule keepInventory true* command on

or

3. There's this other mod which I forget about what it is, but you can use a cheat */back* and you will go back to your death point.

These are all the ways I know and I will edit the answer if I find out more ways.

Comment: What does this add that isn't already in the other answers?

Comment: The /back command

Comment: That's a very vague addition. Strip out the info that's in the other answers and you're left with "A mod I can't remember."

Comment: To be fair, the Death-Chest mod has been answered in triplicate, including one that was answered almost two weeks later, so if you want to complain about duplicate answers, then all three duplicates should be removed.