# If I die in another dimension, will the 5-minute clock start while I am in the overworld?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was recently hit by a fireball and knocked off the edge of my platform in the nether. I landed on an island, and died; my items are still there. If I stay in the overworld for longer than five minutes, will my items disappear?

Similarly, will this happen in The End?

Comment: Note that if you're on multiplayer, the clock *will* be started if *anyone* is near.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11010/what-causes-item-to-disappear-in-minecraft

Comment: wait so its 5 minutes and not two minutes?

Comment: @fireDude67 Yes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the chunk needs to be loaded, which means it must be on the same dimensional plane and nearby.

Answer (score 8):

Minecraft items only are in danger of expiring when they are loaded into memory.

When you're in the overworld, the nether is not loaded (I'm assuming you're in single player?), so take all the time you need.

Comment: Please note: even if you're in the same dimension, if you are far enough away so they are not in a loaded chunk the timer will not start.