# Do dropped items in Minecraft decay, and if so, after how long?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long/What causes item to disappear in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11010/how-long-what-causes-item-to-disappear-in-minecraft)

New Minecraft player and I am trying to dump my wooden tools and rock tools now that I am smelting iron.  My solution so far is to dig a hole away from my dwelling and dropping the items down in it.

Do the items eventually decay?

Comment: which is a possible duplicate of [What persists after a respawn in Minecraft Alpha](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7744/what-persists-after-a-respawn-in-minecraft-alpha)

Comment: The answer is: ["Yes, and it takes 5 minutes"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11010/how-long-what-causes-item-to-disappear-in-minecraft/11011#11011)

Comment: Sorry my question was not about dying and respawning, just dropping items out of your inventory.  I guess the 5 minutes applies to both.

Comment: That's okay, duplicate questions help funnel people toward the correct answer. :)